# Why are my videos playing speeded up with no audio, but work fine if I log in as a guest?

Tags: sound, video

Since the start of this week I have been experiencing a glitch in the multimedia on my Samsung R518 laptop. I have 2 problems:

1. Videos in every player are speeded up around 2 or 4 times (including youtube.com (both HTML5 and flash variants), any other video on the web and videos on my laptop played by Totem Media Player), exception is VLC player, but 2nd problem does concern even that.
2. There is no sound - simple as that (with or without headphones plugged in).

These all problems are now, and has not seen before, I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.10 after it was possible, and from start I didn't have anything from this - it just started in this week. I haven't even putted new software in. I have more or less solved the question (kind of) - I just logged in as a guest - and it all works, but when I make a new user - it does not.

Please help me.
Some stats below:

**sudo lshw -c sound**

```
  *-multimedia            
       description: Audio device
       product: RV710/730
       vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
       resources: irq:48 memory:cfeec000-cfeeffff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1b
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=HDA Intel latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:fc200000-fc203fff
```

**sudo lshw -c video**

```
 *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: M92 LP [Mobility Radeon HD 4300 Series]
       vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:cfef0000-cfefffff memory:cfe00000-cfe1ffff
```

Comment: I more ore less solved question (kind a) - I just logged in as a guest - and it all works, but when I make a new user - it does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you can play the videos with another User Account, it must be a personal setting. If it is a setting of vlc for example, you may reset the settings by deleting the

`~/.vlc/`

completely and start it again. Does this work? If not, i have no idea which system settings may cause such a problem.